# How much do Hong Kong banks charge to cash U.S. checks

Tags: banking, money-transfer, international, check, hong-kong

Do they charge a %, or is it a flat fee?

Comment: Is this an on-topic question?  Seems like banking policies of Hong Kong banks can change over time and are not personal finance tenets. If you want to know how much a Hong Kong bank charges for something, _ask a bank in Hong Kong_.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Bank. Most Hong Kong Banks will charge a flat fee, though the fee varies from bank-to-bank (typically between HK$10 - HK$40). Pretty much any major bank will cash a Traveler's Check or a Certified Check, but if you are talking about a regular check, you will likely have to use a bank that has branches in both the U.S. and Hong Kong like HSBC, and then there may be a 2-3 day waiting period depending on how long you've had an account with the bank and what your account standing with them is.

Answer (score 0):

In Hong Kong, there are two ways to cash a US check.

**Clean bills purchased by receiving bank**

Fee: 0.25% to 0.375% on lump sum

Time: Immediate if you have a good standing history and collateral, e.g. time deposit. About 1 week otherwise.

**Clean bills sent for collection**

Fee: HKD 100 - 300 Fixed

Time: Up to 4 weeks

---

Fees vary from bank to bank, relationship balance, creditworthiness of the check (e.g. corporate vs personal vs treasury).

---

Reference

https://www.personal.hsbc.com.hk/1/content/hongkongpws/pdf/bank-tariff.pdf (Page 8)

https://www.dbs.com.hk/iwov-resources/pdf/ratesfees/notice-bankcharges.pdf (Page 6)

https://www.citibank.com.hk/english/banking/pdf/service_fee.pdf (Page 6)